# Best practice for tracking in page javascript interactions w/ Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics

I have a question regarding best practice for a Google Analytics implementation.

I have a website that has static pages, on which there are several opportunities for javascript interaction. I'm interested in what the best practice is for tracking these interactions.

**For Example:** There is a button that prompts a modal where users can join a mailing list. On this modal, there is another button for users to submit their email address. I want to know how many people click the prompt button, and how many people continue to submit their email address.

To my knowledge there are two approaches on this--

1. Events - Trigger an event when the modal is prompted, and a second event when the information is entered and submitted.
2. Pageloads - Programatically trigger a pageload for each modal dialog.

If I use events, I can track the activity, but don't have access to good funneling tools when I set up conversions. There is the 'Event Funneling Report', but it doesn't give me to give the other correlation tools available with conversions.

I do have access to conversion funneling if I trigger pageloads, but the interactions are not pageloads, and I don't want to skew my other traffic metrics.

What is the best thing to do in this scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I too wish GA would expand on event tracking to allow the funnels to be more like the page view funnels. I have yet to see any real argument about why they can't.. But there's no real best practice for this other than going with the limitation you are more willing to deal with.

A couple of suggestions though:

- If you go the page load route, prefix it w/ something unique e.g. "~events/..." something that wouldn't normally be a page on your site, so that you can more easily filter them out of your normal pages report. Alternatively, setup a view with a filter that excludes your virtual page name (e.g. "~events/..") so you can see your traffic without it and not have to worry about filtering it out in the reports. Alternatively, create a segment that does the same. None of this offers a perfect solution but it does somewhat help making it less crappy :/
- If you go the event route, also pop a custom variable. help as far as creating a funnel but does open up looking at it through those reports.